# Remove junk characters from end of the line in Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I am getting a data file which is separated by Pipe (|) and there are total 17 columns, at the end of last column there are different junk characters, which we don't want. Last column value if it is present the value is always timestamp i.e. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS, but sometime last column value is not present as well.

I need a way to remove the junk characters from the end of the line if it is there at all.

```
  1|0059019539|12MO-V43|0000000001|0000000001||2015-08-06 15:25:04||2015-08-06 15:25:04|2016-08-05|0000000011|0000000001|-10.00|P000101581|V7|Action|2015-08-05 00:00:00
  1|0059019539|VAGR~V47|0000000001|0000000001||2015-08-06 15:25:04||2015-08-06 15:25:04|2016-08-05|0000000011|0000000001|-33.00|P000101581|33-12MO-V2|Action|2015-08-05 00:00:00^@^@^@^@
```

Here in the example 2nd row is having the junk characters.

Comment: `^@` is not a junk character - it's the caret notation of the [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character).

Comment: For me after the last column value which is timestamp, anything coming is junk and I want to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat ACTUALFILE.DATA|awk -F'|' '{ print $1 "|" $2 "|" $3 "|" $4 "|" $5 "|" $6 "|" $7 "|" $8 "|" $9 "|" $10 "|" $11 "|" $12 "|" $13 "|" $14 "|" $15 "|" $16 "|" substr($17, 1, 19)}' > BACKUPFILE.DATA
```

Answer (score 0):

When your junk is binary, you can try

```
strings ACTUALFILE.DATA > BACKUPFILE.DATA
```